# show php/mysql grabbed images in jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

UPDATE: solution found and updated in posted code

as it currently stands i have the images stored in a directory on my system which i am hosting an iis server on (this server is a lcoalserver but im coding to have it work on the public web too). any way i am able to grab these images fine and output them in the correct spot using the code here -

```
<?php
$profileQuery = "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE uploadEmail ='".$_SESSION['friendEmail']."' ORDER BY uploadDate DESC;";
$profileResult = mysqli_query($connect,$profileQuery);
while($rowSize = $profileResult->fetch_assoc()){    
echo "<tr><td><img class='img' id='".$rowSize['id']."' src='".$rowSize['filepath']."' title='Upload Date: ".$rowSize['uploadDate']."' height='250' alt='File Name: ".$rowSize['filepath']." Upload Date: ".$rowSize['uploadDate']."'></td></tr>";}
?>
```

However i want to know if theres a way so when i click an image on the page, it opens a jquery dialog, and displays said image in the dialog. I have the dialog appearing fine, but had no luck making the image appear.

```
<div id="modal" style="display: none;">
<p>i am test data</p><!--this shows up in dialog-->
<img id="insertImage"></img>
<!--<?php 
echo "
<script>
document.getElementById('".$rowSize['id']."');
</script>
"
?>--><!--this php code made the site throw an error 500(edit: php code removed))-->
<form>
<input type='button' style='width:100%;' name='close' class='ibtni' value='Close!' id='close'/>
</form>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function() {
$('#modal').dialog({
autoOpen: false,
modal: true,
title: "Image",
draggable: false,
resizable: false,
closeOnEscape: false,
dialogClass: "noclose"
});
$('.img').click(function() {
$("#insertImage").attr("src",this.src);//makes picture load in image placeholder in the div
$('#modal').dialog('open');
});
});
$('#close').click(function() {
$('#modal').dialog('close');
});
});
</script>
```

any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: where should i be inseting "mysqli_real_escape_string" to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try my sample code below.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <image class="img"
               style="height: 100px; width: 100px"
               src="https://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/mt/2017/10/Pict1_Ursinia_calendulifolia/lead_720_405.jpg?mod=1533691909">
        </image>


        <image class="img"
               style="height: 100px; width: 100px"
               src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1499018658500-b21c72d7172b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
        </image>

        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <image id="insertImage"></image>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $('.img').click(function() {
        $("#insertImage").attr("src",this.src);
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
      });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how would i sub my image links for yours? my image lings are currently designed the way they are because i dont know exactly how many images a use may upload. or do i not need to have an image id or class now?

Comment: I updated the code above, just use the javascript. Unfortunately I don't know the rest of your codes, in able to show you how this will work to your codes.

Comment: thank you, the only lines i ended up needing was this html
`<image id="insertImage"></image>`
and this java script
`$("#insertImage").attr("src",this.src);`
ill fix my code above